# how to compare t-test in certain date ranges?

Tags: r, statistics, t-test

I have a standard group for date i.e. 4-30-7.2005

and my reference dates are 4-30.7.2003 and 4-30.7.2004

Now i have to compare the mean of my standard group with mean of reference dates. i.e. 4-30.7.2004 to 4-30.7.2004.

I am using t-test to compare means separated by years using the following command:

```
t.test(cvd ~ format(date, "%Y"), data=hw_2010[format(hw_2010$date, "%Y")=="2003" | format(hw_2010$date, "%Y")=="2004",])
```

this is working fine.

But how can I put reference years altogether in one group and compare those to the standard group using a t-test? can someone please help me with the code?

Edited: I am applying the following formula for comparison:

```
t.test(cvd ~ format(date, "%Y")=="2010", data=hw_2010[format(hw_2010$date, "%Y") %in% c("2007","2008","2009", "2010", "2012", "2013"),])
```

but i am getting following error from R:

```
Error in t.test.formula(cvd ~ format(date, "%Y") == "2010", data = hw_2010[format(hw_2010$date,  :
```

grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

**This is fixed**

Comment: Ideally we should have some sample data we can run to test our code. can you share the results of `dput(head(hw_2010))` to get an idea of the data structure? The error implies that format(date, "%Y") == "2010" does not produce two groups (i.e. some TRUE and some FALSE). What does `summary(format(hw_2010$date, "%Y")=="2010")` produce?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can simplify to:

`t.test(cvd ~ format(date, "%Y"), data=hw_2010[format(hw_2010$date, "%Y") %in% c("2003","2004"),])`

If I understand correctly, you want to compare 2003 and 2004 *versus* 2005?

If so, then try:

`t.test(cvd ~ format(date, "%Y")=="2005", data=hw_2010[format(hw_2010$date, "%Y") %in% c("2003","2004","2005"),])`

In the t-test results `mean in group TRUE` is your reference group.

Comment: i am having this error while applying the script you said . Please see my edited version of question

Comment: But i don't understand why we are putting the 2005 again with rest of years? we have already told in formula that we are using 2005 as comparison year?

Comment: The `data=` argument is specifying the dataset we want to *apply* the formula to. whereas the `~ foo` part tells us what to do with that dataset to create two groups to compare. So we need a `data` which has both comparison groups (i.e. 2003/2004 and 2005) and then we use the formula to make 2005 group "TRUE" and 2003/2004 group "FALSE" and then it will run the t.test comparing the means of these two groups.